# skin detection in the YUV color space?

Tags: image-processing, yuv

can i perform skin detection using a set of rules (things like x1 < Y < x2 )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is **yes**, you can.

However, luminance (Y) is actually **irrelevant**.  It's the **chrominance** (CbCr or UV) that matters.

One of the most cited papers in this area is [this one](http://www.se.ecu.edu.au/~dchai/public/papers/csvt99.ps) (uncompressed PS file).  I've implemented it and it seems to work fairly well.

UPDATE: the link above seems to have become broken, so here is the bibtex citation of the paper:

```
@ARTICLE{767122, 
author={Chai, D. and Ngan, K.N.}, 
journal={Circuits and Systems for Video Technology, IEEE Transactions on}, title={Face segmentation using skin-color map in videophone applications }, 
year={1999}, 
month={jun}, 
volume={9}, 
number={4}, 
pages={551 -564}, 
keywords={H.261-compliant coder;chrominance component;complex background scene;face-segmentation algorithm;fast algorithm;foreground/background coding;head-and-shoulders view;human skin color;input image;luminance;perceptual quality;pixels;regularization processes;reliable algorithm;simulation results;spatial distribution characteristics;test images;universal skin-color map;video coding;videophone applications;videophone sequence;videotelephony;brightness;image colour analysis;image segmentation;image sequences;video coding;videotelephony;}, 
doi={10.1109/76.767122}, 
ISSN={1051-8215},}
```

Comment: I'm reasonably sure what the answer to this is, but here goes -- @misha, any chance that implementation of yours is available to the public in any capacity?

Comment: Your intuition serves you well :) It's a really trivial paper to implement.  Have a read of it and you'll see for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a link that gives you the rules in RGB:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/RedMatterLibrary.aspx

And here's how to convert between RGB and YUV:

http://www.fourcc.org/fccyvrgb.php

Hope this helps.