# Whiten skin color in an image

Tags: image, ios4, image-processing, ios-4.2

Is there any theory or image filter for whitening the skin color in an image on iPhone ?

I have the RGB data on hand. But whatever I change, it cannot archieve my needs. I alter the RGB as follows:

New value of R/G/B = (int)roundf(Old R/G/B - 128) * contrast_value + 128 + brightness_value);

Where contrast_value = 1 to 1.3 and brightness_value = 0 to 50

But I found that it comes to pale yellow ...

Comment: Next you'll be wondering how to apply this outside of the iPhone... Kind of a scary question. (And honestly hard to imagine a typical use case. Why do you need to lighten the skin tones separately from the rest of an image?)

Comment: A camera application with a WHITENING filter. So whenever a photo is taken, user can adjust to make the face of person more white

Answer (score 2):

Convert your image to [YUV colorspace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV) first.  This gives you two advantages:

1. easily detect skin areas using [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089704/skin-detection-in-the-yuv-color-space) (see my answer to that question)
2. easily increase the brightness (just increment the Y value)

Answer (score 0):

One thing I have seen to work is to add a constand value to all the three components of the color, like R + 0x33 G + 0x33 B + 0x33

EDITED: I just found another thread that has additional information: [Programmatically Lighten a Color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141855/programmatically-lighten-a-color)